# How to get the commits chain for a certain file

Tags: git, git-branch

Say I have a very simple branch like this

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E
*         *         *
```

in which `A`, `C` and `E` changed file `F` (i.e. `B, D` has nothing to do with `F`). What I'm trying to do is to extract `A, B, E` and then recombine them into a new branch:

```
A -- C -- E (new branch)
```

I don't know how to do it or if it's possible. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detach subdirectory into separate Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository)

Comment: You can use `git filter-branch`. Note that whatever you try will effectively create different commits A, C and E, which are incompatible to the original ones.

Comment: @poke, please consider converting your comment into an answer as I think this is the only way to go as `git subtree`, which could carry out *almost* this task automatically, works on subdirectories (subtrees) and not on single files. So yes, a way to solve the problem is to "clone" `E` into a new branch and run properly instrumented `git filter-branch` on it.

Comment: @kostix I would like to have this question closed instead. The linked question shows how to use `filter-branch` in much more detail than I could possibly reproduce here.

Comment: @poke, the page you linked to appears to be quite detailed but keeping a single file is different from keeping a subdirectory... Say, you invoke `git filter-branch --index-filter=...` and pass it what command exactly? `git rm` does not support negative matches (like "everything except whatever matches `*foo`").

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not trying to automate bulk work, the ordinary commands work just fine for this:

```
git checkout --orphan  newbranch $A
# `git rm` everything but the one file here if that's really what you're after
git commit -a
git cherry-pick $C
git cherry-pick $E
```